# Prevent page form reloading after reroute Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, controller, routes, href

I am implementing account verification and part of it is resending email verification.

**Blade**

```
<a href="/register/resend/{{ $objUser->id }}">@lang('localization.clickHere')</a>@lang('localization.toResendEmail')
```

**routes/web**

```
Route::get('register/resend/{id}','Auth\VerificationController@resend');
```

**Controller**

```
public function resend($id, Request $request)
{   
    $user = User::where('id',$id)->firstOrFail();
    Mail::to($user->email)->queue(new ConfirmRegistration($user));

    $messenger = new Messenger($user);
    $messenger->sendSuccess(__(trans('localization.emailSentSuccessfully')));

    return back();
}
```

The issue I am having is that the page reloads (as expected) whenever I trigger the `href`, which leads to the message sent by the `Controller` disappear right away.

Is there a way to prevent the page from reloading but still trigger the `route`? I tried adding `onclick="return false;"` but that seems to prevent `resend` function from running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why dont you use an Ajax call instead?

**HTML:**

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="mailme(this)" user-id="{{ $objUser->id }}">@lang('localization.clickHere')</a>@lang('localization.toResendEmail')
```

**ROUTE:**

```
Route::get('register/resend','Auth\VerificationController@resend');
```

**CONTROLLER:**

```
public function resend(Request $request)
{   
    $user = User::where('id',$request->id)->firstOrFail();
    Mail::to($user->email)->queue(new ConfirmRegistration($user));

    $messenger = new Messenger($user);
    $messenger->sendSuccess(__(trans('localization.emailSentSuccessfully')));

    return response()->json('success');
}
```

**JS (no JQuery):**

```
mailme = function(obj){
  var userID = obj.getAttribute('user-id')
  var xhttp;
  xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      console.log(this.responseText);
    }
  };
  var params = JSON.stringify({ id: userID });

  xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
  xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
  xhttp.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");

  xhttp.open("GET", '{{url("settings/register/resend")}}', true);

  xhttp.send(params);
}
```

**JS (JQuery):**

```
mailme = function(obj){
    var userID = $(obj).attr('user-id')
    $.ajax({
        type : 'Get',
        data : {
            id: userID
        },
        url : '{{url("settings/register/resend")}}',
        dataType : 'json',
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data)
        }
    });
}
```

This way you will trigger the function without the need of reloading the page to send the request to the server. The request is sent via xhttp

Comment: Strangely enough, I get a `GET 404 (Not Found)` error for `register/resend`. Full error: `GET http://example.net/settings/%7B%7Burl(%22register/resend%22)%7D%7D?id=1 404 (Not Found)`

Comment: did you used the one without jquery?

Comment: it has to be inside the blade template to get the `{{}}` directive

Comment: I moved it to the `blade` and used the `JQuery` one. The `url` is now correct, but it still can't find it. `GET http://example.net/register/resend?id=1 404 (Not Found)`

Comment: the route is inside a group? i mean, shouldnt it be `http://example.net/settings/register/resend?id=1` instead `http://example.net/register/resend`?

Comment: It stands on its own. My initial verification route is `Route::get('register/{token}', 'Auth\VerificationController@verify');'` and the url provided by the blade is `/register/<token>`

Comment: Ok, let see, can you accces this route `Route::get('register/resend','Auth\VerificationController@resend');` using the browser?

Comment: That's strange. I actually can't. It doesn't go to the `resend` function.

Comment: Then something is wrong with the routing. Can you ost the entire route.php file

Comment: by the way, a fast solution to your problem would be setting the url in the js to this `/register/resend` but i dont recommend it

Comment: You were right, my `routes` file had an issue. Fixed it and it is all working now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I use Session variable to handle this

at first session variable from start and set its value to true
and on data save I set its value to false.

then I check the value of session variable and route the resubmit to else ware

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).